# function equality in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

How does the JS engine actually compare objects (like function declarations) for equality?

```
var f1 = function(){};
var f2 = function(){};

console.log(f1 === f2);  //false
```

**what is actually happening behind the scenes to determine that the object references are different? Is it comparing memory locations?**

Comment: If you wouldn't expect `new Object() === new Object()`, then why should you expect that `new Function() === new Function()`?

Comment: Just saw your edit. In a nut shell, yes it's comparing memory locations.

Answer (score 5):

Functions are objects.
Different instances of objects are never srict(*or non-strict*) equal.

Strict equality applied by pointer:

```
var a = b = {}, c = {};
console.log(a === b, a === c); // true false
```

Comment: They're never non-strictly equal either.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm just not sured about `toString`-like methods, but seems like truth. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = function() {
    a = 1;
 }; 

 var bar = function() {
    a = 1;
 }; 

alert(foo.toString() == bar.toString());​
```

this will return true.

Comment: Yes but you're just comparing translated `string` values not the actual objects themselves.

Comment: @Mike is right. This has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: Also, you can optimize your code by removing assignments to global `a`

Comment: Hm, for now I'm understand why this answer here. It just demonstrates a tricky(and not always correct) way to compare functions by their code. `foo.toString().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` can be better some cases.

Comment: @Mike yes i have compared string values. Two objects arestored at two different locations. So when we try to compare we are actually trying to compare two different memory locations, those are always different.
If they pointing to same location then only outcome will be true. 
`
var foo = function() {
    a = 1;
 }; 

 var bar = foo;
alert( foo == bar )`

Comment: Sure but that isn't what OP was asking.

Answer (score -4):

`==` checks if the **Values** are equal

`===` checks if the **Values** are equal along with the **variable type or  return type**

Comment: Functions don't have argument and return types in Javascript.